# Don't wait for an async function to finish

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I have a async tornado server that calls an async function. However, that function just does some background processing, and I don't want to wait for it to finish. How can I do this? Here is an example of what I have:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    yield self.process('data') # I don't want to wait here
    self.write('page')

    @gen.coroutine
    def process(self, arg):
        d = yield gen.Task(self.otherFunc, arg)
        raise gen.Return(None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the yield before self.process('data'). It will still run, but the get function won't wait for it to finish. Example:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    print 'a'
    yield self.process('data') # I don't want to wait here
    print 'b'
    self.write('page')

@gen.coroutine
def process(self, arg):
    print 'c'
    d = yield gen.Task(self.otherFunc, arg)
    print 'd'
    raise gen.Return(None)
```

Will give a,c,d,b but:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    print 'a'
    self.process('data') # I don't want to wait here
    print 'b'
    self.write('page')

@gen.coroutine
def process(self, arg):
    print 'c'
    d = yield gen.Task(self.otherFunc, arg)
    print 'd'
    raise gen.Return(None)
```

Can give a,c,b,d or a,b,c,d depending on order execution, but it will no longer wait until process is done to get to 'b'.

Comment: Note that if "process" raises an exception you won't log it anywhere; it will remain unreported in the Future that you haven't yielded. Consider using an ExceptionStackContext around the site where you call process(), in order to log any errors it raises:

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/stack_context.html

Comment: In Tornado 4.0 you should use IOLoop.spawn_callback to launch a callback that is dissociated from its caller's context.  The IOLoop will log any error that is contained in the Future.  http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.spawn_callback