# run function parallel on python tornado

Tags: python, parallel-processing, tornado, coroutine

I'm currently developing in `python3` (still beginner) on a `tornado` framework and I have a function which I would like to run in the background. To be more precise the task of the function is to download a big file (chunk by chunk) and probably do some more things after each chunk is downloaded. But the calling function should not wait for the download-function to complete but should rather continue execution.

Here some code examples:

```
@gen.coroutine
def dosomethingfunc(self, env):
    print("Do something")

    self.downloadfunc(file_url, target_path) #I don't want to wait here

    print("Do something else")


@gen.coroutine
def downloadfunc(self, file_url, target_path):

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(file_url)
    CHUNK = 16 * 1024

    with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = response.read(CHUNK)
            if not chunk:
                break
            f.write(chunk)
            time.sleep(0.1) #do something after a chunk is downloaded - sleep only as example
```

I've read this answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083098/2492068 and tried use it.

Actually I thought if I use `@gen.coroutine` but no `yield` the `dosomethingfunc` would continue without waiting for `downloadfunc` to finish. But actually the behaviour is the same (with yield or without) - `"Do something else`" will only be printed after `downloadfunc` finished the download.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To benefit of Tornado's asynchronous there must be `yielded` a non-blocking function at some point. Since the code of `downloadfunc` is all blocking, the `dosomethingfunc` does not get back control until called function is finished.

There are couples issue with your code:

- `time.sleep` is blocking, use [`tornado.gen.sleep`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep) instead,
- urllib's `urlopen` is blocking, use [`tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html)

So the `downloadfunc` could look like:

```
@gen.coroutine
def downloadfunc(self, file_url, target_path):

    client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    # below code will start downloading and
    # give back control to the ioloop while waiting for data
    res = yield client.fetch(file_url)

    with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(res)
        yield tornado.gen.sleep(0.1)
```

To implement it with streaming (by chunk) support, you might want to do it like this:

```
# for large files you must increase max_body_size
# because deault body limit in Tornado is set to 100MB

tornado.web.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_body_size=2*1024**3)

@gen.coroutine
def downloadfunc(self, file_url, target_path):

    client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    # the streaming_callback will be called with received portion of data
    yield client.fetch(file_url, streaming_callback=write_chunk)

def write_chunk(chunk):
    # note the "a" mode, to append to the file
    with open(target_path, 'ab') as f:
        print('chunk %s' % len(chunk))
        f.write(chunk)
```

Now you can call it in `dosomethingfunc` without `yield` and the rest of the function will proceed.

**edit**

Modifying the chunk size is not supported (exposed), both from server and client side. You may also look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/K8zerl1JB5o

Comment: Thank you very much for your example - I wasn't aware about the function to block all the time, but sure it makes sense. Unfortunately I tried to implement your solution but I get a "Content-Length" too long Exeption (my file is roughly about 1,5GB). But it shouldn't be a problem using a chunked download. Any idea why I get this message?

Comment: Tornado has body limit set to 100MB, you can overwrite it with `max_body_size` eg. `AsyncHTTPClient(max_body_size=2000000000)`

Comment: I tried usnig `AsyncHTTPClient(max_body_size=2000000000)` but it has no effect for me - the body size remains the same. If I try the same with SimpleAsyncHTTPClient it works BUT how can I define the chunk-size? I can see from my networking monitor that it starts downloading but after 20sec (probably because of the standard-timeout) it just timeouts without writing a chunk. Is there any way to define the chunk size?

Comment: Ok, I found out that the `@gen.coroutine` annotation is necessary for write_chunk. Not it works :-) ... would be still interesting to know if it is possible to define a chunk size? Moreover I can not limit the download/write speed with gen.sleep because it has no effect in terms of async calls